# scroll position issue in PrimeFaces p:media component

Tags: primefaces

On viewing the dialog with pdf for the second time, the previously set scroll position is retained.
How we can set the scroll position of `<p:media./>` to the beginning each time we display it.

Note: Same behavior in all browsers like Firefox, IE.

```
<p:media value="#{plainInvoiceImportData.streamedContent}" player="pdf" width="1000" height="500">
```

Comment: 2 untested ideas: try with cache="false" and update the dialog just before showing it. Or give it an id so you can grab the js-object in the console of your browser, and look for a relevant method (like scrollTo(x) or reset() or something)